# Recognition of face details as a set of points, not just rectangles

Tags: opencv, face-recognition, emotion

I'm doing research in the field of emotion recognition. For this purpose I need to catch and classify particular face details like eyes, nose, mouth, etc. Standard OpenCV function for this is `detectMultiScale()`, but its disadvantage is that it returns list of *rectangles* ([video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V7UdYzCMKvw)) while I'm mostly interested in **particular key points** - corners of mouth, upper and lower points, edges, etc ([video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=45eLpzk6N34)).

So, how do they do it? OpenCV is ideal, but other solutions are ok too.

Comment: Hey I am facing the same issue. I am working on a project for emotion recognition. Can you please help me out? Can you please tell me how did you manage to get the points?

Comment: @shalki: hey, as suggested by Abid, I used AAMs to get points - these models work really well and do exactly what I need. I tried several AAM implementations in different programming languages, but finished up with with Matlab-based [ICAAM](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/32704-icaam-inverse-compositional-active-appearance-models) ([full version](http://sourceforge.net/projects/icaam/)). Even if are not going to use Matlab version, consider downloading it at least for included papers. Let me know if you need further clarification.

Comment: hey so you mean you directly used an AAM library? Can you help me out by giving me how can I actually start with it's implementation?

Comment: @shalki: Yes, I used ICAAM library to analyze images of faces, though I'm currently experimenting with some of its components. If you want to implement AAMs from scratch, consider [this paper](http://www.itu.dk/stud/projects_f2004/handtracking/referencer/Cootes%20den%20lange%20-%20app_model.pdf) as the most detailed description of all aspects of AAMs.

Comment: hey need your help. Can I have a chat? As I find it to be a bit difficult to explain my problem here and it won't even be related to the question. Thanks.

Comment: @ffriend Hi, I'm looking to do a similar thing: I want to detect the corners of the eyes. Have you found a way in your case? Can you please guide me?

Comment: @GhadaSalem: first of all, take a look at [FaceTracker](https://github.com/kylemcdonald/FaceTracker) library - may be this will be sufficient for you. On other hand, you can try to do it via edge detection (see link from the answer below for some ideas) - in theory it can be both simpler and more efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To analyse such precise points, you can use [Active appearance models.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_appearance_model) Your second video seems to be done with AAM. Check out above wikipedia link, where you can get a lot of AAM tools and API.

On the other hand, if you can detect mouth using haar-cascade, apply colour filtering. Obviously lips and surrounding region has color difference. You get precise model of lips and find its edges.

Check out this paper: [Lip Contour Extraction](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=lip%20segmentation&source=web&cd=4&ved=0CEAQFjAD&url=http://www.eurecom.fr/util/publidownload.en.htm?id=3142&ei=Vt0gT5nuF8nUrQeY6JW4CA&usg=AFQjCNEo3YLdUMYLJ3xUkyrr_jAVkdf-tg)